# Phone Gap Windows Build access rule

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-build, phonegap-gmaps-plugin

When I build cordova build for windows the access rules are failing, following are the information in the console

Access rules must begin with "https://", the following rule will be ignored: .*

Basically it saying it require to begin with https,

Anybody face the same issue.

Thanks
Mohsin

Comment: [This blogger](https://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/)  has information on using Windows with Phonegap Build - [Workflow](https://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/workflow/)

Answer (score 1):

The warnings can be ignored... sort of.

Windows builds break on non-https access rules, so in order to prevent Windows builds from failing while still allowing other platforms to use non-https rules, [cordova filters out the non-https rules while preparing a windows build](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7377?focusedCommentId=14110502&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14110502).

Those "rule will be ignored" messages appearing in your console are to let you know the rule has been filtered out before building the Windows project. If the app depends on access granted by a rule that is being filtered out, add another one that meets the Windows rule requirements.

More specifically:

- Access rules (`<access origin=...>`) must begin with ["https://", or be "*"](https://git1-us-west.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-windows.git;a=blob;f=template/cordova/lib/prepare.js;hb=033956d1f561a0d3321199115d7b556ea6ed7d8e#l245)
- Navigation rules (`<allow-navigation...>`) must begin with ["http://", "https://", or "ms-appx-web://"](https://git1-us-west.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-windows.git;a=blob;f=template/cordova/lib/prepare.js;hb=033956d1f561a0d3321199115d7b556ea6ed7d8e#l272)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using white-list rules, and you did NOT provide `phonegap-version` in your config.xml, you get the latest version. It is good to add version to your config.xml and all your plugins

EXAMPLE additions

```
::
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.5.0" />
::
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.12" />
```

In addition, you need to use the `white-list` plugin.
Please read the following "official" form post:
*Notes for upgrading to cli-5.1.1 on PGB*
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/notes-for-upgrading-to-cli-5-1-1-on-pgb